# Installing R packages available for all users

Tags: r, installation, package

I have a few R packages installed under `~/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.11`.

I would like to make them, and any other R package I install from now on, available to all R users. I don't mind re-installing the packages I already have in a neutral place (they are just a few). So how do I do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

aL3xa gives (IMHO) bad advice. Do not mess with `/usr` which is handled by the package management system. Instead, use the facility provided by `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`.

That latter directory is already searched by default. All you need to do is to add yourself to group `staff` as that group has write-rights there -- try `adduser yourid staff` where `yourid` is your user name on the system.  Afterwards you should be able to install there without problems.

Another thing you may like on Ubuntu is `apt-get install littler` and then use the `install.r` and `upgrade.r` helper scripts from the examples directory. I use them all the time.

Comment: Neat one, definitely a better solution, though you've advertised your product(s)... =) Is `/usre/local...` a typo?

Comment: Well my advertising budget is small :)  Typo fixed -- thanks.

Comment: One more question: `staff` group is another of your products (since you maintain Debian/Ubuntu packages)? It's available only on those packages? If so, I'm migrating back to Ubuntu... maybe! =)

Comment: so how do I set back the permissions suggested by aL3xa (I already ran the loop)

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 0755 /usr/lib/library/R` as 0755 (user write, group and others r) is the default for directories.

Comment: Sorry for my "solution". I'm the one and only user, so it's "safe" to change permissions in my case.

Comment: I added my user to `staff` but when trying to install a package from R I still get `> install.packages("getopt")
Warning in install.packages("getopt") :
  argument 'lib' is missing: using '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
Warning in install.packages("getopt") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to create a personal library
'~/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.11'
to install packages into?  (y/n) `

Comment: Please consider posting the question on r-sig-debian.

Comment: Where can I find more info about install.r and upgrade.r of the littler program? thanks

Comment: They are (really short) examples in the littler package, just as it says in the third paragraph of my answer above.

Comment: This answer was very helpful, but is missing a few details. After adding yourself to the `staff` group, you need to log out and back in for it to have effect (hence David B's error). But how to tell R to install in `/usr/local/...`? I found one method: `install.packages('foo', '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library')`.

Comment: Yes, logging in and out (ie creating a new session for you) is required. The location is normally the default on Debian-based systems; littler which has been mentioned here also sets it in `install.r` and now also `install2.r`.

Comment: After having searched I guess this is the question that matches mine to the closest, hence not creating a new question. Request @DirkEddelbuettel to kindly enlighten us, in which situation is package installed in each of these directories:  `[1] "/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                  
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                         "/usr/lib/R/library"     `. It has left be floundering for answers when I see 128 packages are lying in the first directory, 90 in the second, 1 in the third and 15 in the fourth.

Comment: @Sanjay: This is a eight+ years old question and answer, but I answered similar questions many times over.  Keep looking for other answers  In short: unless something else is specified _the first_ position in `.libPaths()` is used.

Comment: Did a little bit more searches and the situation appears murkier than earlier. I chanced upon your excellent advice here https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2018-May/002833.html and now am thinking if I made a mistake to leap forward to instal 3.5.2 on my ubuntu server. Would you still go by your advice of avoiding the jump, or has the situation changed and R 3.5.2 on ubuntu 16 installation is now well documented and robust?

Comment: @Sanjay May I ask you to stop this subthread here?  It really is not the right place. Post on r-sig-debian and describe your situation and concerns.  FWIW I run the current R 3.5.2 (via the CRAN-mirrored apt repository) on several current Ubuntu 18.10 machines.

Answer (score 9):

aL3xa answer is wrong; you shouldn't expose those directories to write for all users.
Run R as a root (probably using `sudo R`) and then install packages as usual -- they will be placed in a global library and will be available for all users.

Comment: Or add yourself to group `staff` as I wrote and you don't need `sudo` to run as root.

Comment: maintenance question: what happens if you update the packages at the same time as another user has the package loaded?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the easiest way would be to install the packages as root (or as administrator in case of Windows), they'll be available for every user on that machine.