# How do I set R_LIBS_SITE on Ubuntu so that .libPaths() is set properly for all users at startup?

Tags: r, package

I am setting up a cluster where all nodes have access to `/nfs/software`, so a good place to `install.packages()` would be under `/nfs/software/R`.  How do I set `R_LIBS_SITE` so that this is automatically part of all users' R environment?  I tried prepending to the path given for R_LIBS_SITE in `/etc/R/Renviron` but `help(Startup)` says "do not change ‘R_HOME/etc/Renviron’ itself", which I'm not sure is the same file since `R_HOME` expands to `/usr/lib/R`, but has no effect in any case.  Making entries in the various `Renviron.site` and `Rprofile.site` files does not seem to have the desired effect.  What am I missing here?

Some other questions have danced around this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615128/where-does-r-store-packages) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487329/installing-r-packages-available-for-all-users), maybe others), but people seem to settle for having a user-specific library in their `HOME`.

Comment: It was failing silently because the library folder `/nfs/software/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13` had not been created yet.  Editing the `R_LIBS_SITE= `. . . line in /etc/R/Renviron still seems like the way to go.  The desired path is the first entry in `.libPaths()` now, but `update.packages()` did its work in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`, the second entry.  What is going on here?

Comment: I finally realized that I had to log in to the NFS server, set up R there, change the `/etc` files, and install the packages from there because of NFS root squashing.  I'm sure Dirk is correct on all points, but I'm moving on with what I have done since it seems to be working.  Thanks for letting me document a stream of consciousness here while I work this out!  I hope this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have owner and/or group write permissions for the directory you want to write into.

The file `/etc/R/Renviron.site` is the preferred choice for local overrides to `/etc/R/Renviron`.

Another way is to simply ... impose the directory when installing packages. I tend to do that on the (bash rather than R) shell via this script derived from an example in the littler package:

```
$ cat bin/install.r 
#!/usr/bin/env r
#
# a simple example to install one or more packages

if (is.null(argv) | length(argv)<1) {

  cat("Usage: installr.r pkg1 [pkg2 pkg3 ...]\n")
  q()

}

## adjust as necessary, see help('download.packages')
repos <- "http://cran.us.r-project.org"
#repos <- "http://cran.r-project.org"

## this makes sense on Debian where no packages touch /usr/local
lib.loc <- "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"

install.packages(argv, lib.loc, repos)
```

and you can easily customize a helper like this for your preferred location. With the script installed in `~/bin/`, I often do

```
$ ~/bin/install.r xts plyr doRedis
```

and it will faithfully install these packages along with their depends. The littler package has a similar script `update.r`.

Comment: after all of that I tried `littler` for the first time and I get this:  `$ r -e "print(.libPaths())"
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"`  Does `r` start up differently in this respect?

Comment: On a system where I do not have `~/R/library/`, `r` and `Rscript` give the same result.  On the other hand, where `~/R/library/` exists. `Rscript` adds it to the front.  There may be new startup code in `R` which `r` does not do.  I tend not to use `~/R/library/` so current behaviour is fine by me.

Comment: Note, setting R_LIBS_SITE in `/etc/R/Renviron.site` means the setting won't be respected if R is started with a `--vanilla` flag. If you want to set the default `R_LIBS_SITE` more permanently (so the setting persists even with `--vanilla`), , the only options are to set it at outside of R (e.g., `/etc/bashrc`), modify `/etc/R/Renviron` (against official recommendations, but seemingly harmless), or to build R from source with the site-lib specified, perhaps thought `--prefix=` or similar.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `--vanilla` is for: it is meant to skip the init files, and generally just a debugging too.  Setting in options in the different `*.site` is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

follow-up on Dirk Eddelbuettel (thanks Dirk!)

an adaptation of Dirk's suggestion that may be run within R:

```
# R function to install one or more packages
Rinstall <- function(pkg) {
  if (is.null(pkg) | length(pkg)<1) {
    q()
  }
  if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
  lib.dir <- "c:/R/library"
  } else {
  lib.dir <- "~/R/library"
  }
  repos.loc <- "http://cran.us.r-project.org"
  install.packages(pkg, lib.dir, repos.loc, dependencies=c('Depends','Suggests'))  # make sure you get dependencies
}
```

Usage:

```
Rinstall(c("package1", "package2"))
```

Naturally you want to adapt the repos.loc and lib.dir based on your system. As I work on both Windows and Linux machines I also inserted a conditional statement to check which system I'm on.

P.S. Don't hesitate to simplify the code, I'm a total newbie.