# How to set R_LIBS_SITE or how to share package site?

Tags: r, package

This is a somewhat generalized version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218358/). How do I set `R_LIBS_SITE`? I am not able to get proper values for it on both CentOS 7.2 and openSUSE 42.1 with the most recent R 3.3.1.

On CentOS 7.2 (Linux x86_64) with R from EPEL I get:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
...
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
...
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/lib64/R/library" "/usr/share/R/library"
> .Library
[1] "/usr/lib64/R/library"
> .Library.site
[1] "/usr/lib64/R/library" "/usr/share/R/library"
> R.home(component = "home")
[1] "/usr/lib64/R"
```

However, the respective Renviron includes the following:

```
$ grep R_LIBS_SITE /usr/lib64/R/etc/Renviron
R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/local/lib/R/library:/usr/lib64/R/library:/usr/share/R/library'}
```

Apparently, this setting is not applied properly when I start R. However,
changes for example in R_LIBS_USER in the same file are applied. In addition, `R_LIBS_SITE` is not ignored completely because setting it to

```
R_LIBS_SITE='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
```

produces

```
> .Library.site
character(0)
```

I don't see where `R_LIBS_SITE` could be overwritten elsewhere. I get
the same behaviour in R when I start it with

```
R --no-environ --no-site-file --no-init-file
```

I can reproduce a similar behaviour with openSUSE.

Or is there another recommended way to set a package site shared amongst all users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible explanation of the problem is that some of the directories do not exist. Directories that do not exist are silently removed from the list. So, if you set

`R_LIBS_SITE='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'`

and the directory does not exist, `.Library.site` will be an empty string (like in your example). Following the outputs from your example, if directories `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` and `/usr/local/lib/R/library` do not exist, they will be silently removed from the list given in `R_LIBS_SITE` of your `Renviron` file (again like in your output).