# Install R package to correct library path in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have uploaded an R package onto my Ubuntu server. I then install this package into R library as follows:

```
install.packages('my_package', repo=NULL, dir='/usr/lib/R/library')
```

All other packages are installed in the /usr/lib/R/library directory as confirmed by running:

```
installed.packages()
```

and viewing the LibPath column.

I then add to library using:

```
library(my_package,lib.loc="/usr/lib/R/library")
```

but when I run installed.packages() and view the LibPath column I can see that it was added to a different directory. The directory looks like:

```
/home/my_server/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3
```

How can I install my package into the correct directory on Ubuntu?

Also tried:

```
install.packages('my_package', repo=NULL, lib.loc='/usr/lib/R/library')
```

Also tried changing the write permissions to that folder. Still doesn't work. No matter what I try, it always places my package in  /home/my_server/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3

Comment: do you want to change your directory permanently ?

Comment: No, I am happy to use just the one directory. I just need to upload my package to that one directory.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it to work by changing the write permissions using:

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 '/usr/lib/R/library'
```

Comment: It is probably safer to change the owner in the folder, instead of giving 777 permissions? 
`sudo chown myuser:myuser /usr/lib/R/library/ * -R`

Comment: Please, dear readers, don't do this on a multi-user system. You might as well hang a sign "DEPOSIT YOUR EVIL-DOING SCRIPTS HERE" or "PLEASE `rm -rf` ME AT A VERY INCONVENIENT TIME" Gorka's proposed alternative works fine (if you remove the errant `*`) if it's just your personal system. Under all other conditions, consider literally any other alternative, even installing that one package as root.

Answer (score 0):

Safe and recommended alternatives have already been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218358/how-do-i-set-r-libs-site-on-ubuntu-so-that-libpaths-is-set-properly-for-all-u/6219143#6219143) [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487329/installing-r-packages-available-for-all-users/3487684#3487684), so this question should probably be closed as a duplicate.

But if it's just the one package, consider doing the install as root using `sudo`. This feels dirty, but if you're looking for a quick fix, this is slightly better than opening up a system directory for write access to all users henceforth. Except if that package contains malware, I guess.

It's typically advised that you don't mess with the "system" libraries, though, which are the domain of the package manager, *i.e.*, `apt` on Ubuntu. As for a better long-term alternative, the short answer is: consider using `/usr/local` for locally-installed (as opposed to system-installed) packages. This is [what `/usr/local` *is for*](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html#purpose24).

You can add yourself to the `staff` group on Ubuntu (or whatever particular "admin" group applies to your distro) and then grant yourself full-time access to `/usr/local` like this:

```bash
# you will need to log out and back in for this to take effect
sudo usermod -aG staff $USER

# assuming a local ext3/4 filesystem
# grant 'staff' read/write for existing files r/w/x for existing dirs
sudo setfacl -R -m g:staff:rwX /usr/local
# also apply these by default to new files and directories
sudo setfacl -R -d -m g:staff:rwX /usr/local
```

I'm not nearly an expert with configuring R for a large site, so please do your own research. However, based on observation, `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` is *already* the first path in `R_LIBS_SITE` as defined in the factory-installed `/etc/R/Renviron` on Debian/Ubuntu, which suggests it's the correct place for a local admin to install packages.

So, [*if* that directory exists on the filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685859/how-to-set-r-libs-site-or-how-to-share-package-site/39766163#39766163) *and* you have read/write access to it, then future `install.packages` as your regular user will just "do the right thing" and go into `/usr/local`:

```r
> .Library.site
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"       

> install.packages("lubridate")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
⋮
```

Hope that helps.