# How do I install R packages into system library on Linux?

Tags: r, shiny, package, shiny-server

Regardless of whether I run `R` or `sudo R`, when I then run `install.packages("name")` the packages always gets installed into `/home/james/R/...` as opposed to a system library.

(I need the packages in the system library so that Shiny Server can find them)

How do I make R install into the system library instead of a user specific one?

Comment: This is likely solved by using [`.libPaths`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html).

Comment: Also possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37690130/3358272

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [Dean Attali's guide](https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/#user-libraries) to setting up a shiny server:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('<PACKAGE>', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

My understanding is that you're essentially installing the package globally as the root user so that any user can access it. Seems to work well for me so far.