# Reload Custom R Package from Source

Tags: r, microsoft-r, deployr

I have created a custom package and would like to deploy it to a remote machine. Here is my current long workflow:

- Create custom package 'my_package_0.1.0.tar.gz'
- scp package to remote machine
- create Remote session
- `install.packages("/path/to/my_package0.1.0.tar.gz")`
- `library('my_package')`

When others connect to the machine, they have to run install and library:

- `install.packages("/path/to/my_package0.1.0.tar.gz")`
- `library('my_package')`

Is there a way I can share a custom package and have the workflow be:

- Create remote session
- Load package with `library('my_package')`

Comment: You don't have administrative access to the remote machine? In which case you could install the package system-wide.

Comment: This may also be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487329/installing-r-packages-available-for-all-users

Comment: An alternative might be to keep your package as a script, and upload it online e.g., to github.  That way, users can simply source your script from github, and it will be always up to date.

Comment: It looks like remote connections store files in a location like /opt/deployr/9.0.1/rserve/workdir/Rserv8.0.5/connXXX. Where is a more appropriate location for shared files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feedback in comments says the best practice is to install the package in a shared location.

Here is how you can find a good place to install the packages.

Running the following shows where libraries are loaded from

```
.libPaths()
# rserve2 rserve2 /opt/deployr/9.0.1/rserve/R
#root root        /usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/library
```

There are two locations the R server is looking for libraries. One is owned by root so we shouldn't deploy here. The other location rserve2 has owndership and looks promising. We should create a `library` subfolder to store the shared packages.

Based on this information, the work flow should be:

- Create custom package 'my_package_0.1.0.tar.gz'
- scp package to remote machine
- create Remote session
- install.packages("/path/to/my_package0.1.0.tar.gz", **lib='/opt/deployr/9.0.1/rserve/R/library/'**)
- library('my_package')

When others connect to the machine, they can load the shared library:

- library('my_package')